# How to make this SQL query shorter?

Tags: sql, sql-update

How to make this SQL query shorter?

```
UPDATE users SET password = 'password1' WHERE username = 'user1';
UPDATE users SET password = 'password2' WHERE username = 'user2';
UPDATE users SET password = 'password3' WHERE username = 'user3';
```

I'm a novice in SQL, so I need your help:)

Comment: This is the shortest query you can write and it is recommended to write it in that way.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression here along with just a single update:

```
UPDATE users
SET password = CASE username WHEN 'user1' THEN 'password1'
                             WHEN 'user2' THEN 'password2'
                             WHEN 'user3' THEN 'password3' END
WHERE username IN ('user11', 'user2', 'user3');
```

This being said, there is an even bigger problem with what you are doing, namely that you seem to be storing clear text passwords in your users table.  Don't do this; instead, irreversibly hash the clear text password, and then store this hash in the table.  Then, should anyone malicious ever get a hold of your table, they wouldn't be able to figure out the actual passwords.

Comment: I know about a hash, but I didn't want to write the hash here) These passwords were like examples

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression to perform the operation in a single query:

```
update users set password = case username
    when 'user1' then 'password1'
    when 'user2' then 'password2'
    when 'user3' then 'password3'
end
where username in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3)
```